# Unable to display JsonResponse in Django web project

Tags: python, json, django, jsonresponse

I am working on a django project. I want to display the result of a query with JsonResponse, but I can only get the raw data, rather than the colourful Json response.

Here is my code

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import connection
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'AppTPCC/index.html')


def result(request):
    search_string = request.GET.get('name', '')
    query = 'SELECT * FROM item WHERE i_name ~ \'%s\'' % (search_string)
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute(query)
    results = c.fetchall()
    result_dict = {'records': results}
    return render(request, 'AppTPCC/result.html', result_dict)


def query(request):
    query = """ SELECT w.w_country, SUM(s.s_qty) FROM warehouse w, stock s, item i
                WHERE i.i_name = 'Aspirin' AND i.i_id = s.i_id AND w.w_id = s.w_id
                GROUP BY w.w_country; """
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute(query)
    results = c.fetchall()
    return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.index),
    re_path(r'result', views.result),
    re_path(r'query', views.query, name='query'),
]
```

Then when I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/AppTPCC/query` in my browser, I can only get the raw data type.
I am wondering how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to ***parse*** the `results` with respect to your requirement. Django won't do that for you.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?